# A 500 Internal Server Error while running Google site search

Tags: php, gssapi, gss

This is a first time we are using GSS and applying in our application.

If we search a query in GSS we are getting good result depending upon the websites we have added to be searched from. But if we give GSS around a hundred queries one by one in a for loop, like,

```
   for ($i = 0, $count = count($arr1); $i < $count; $i++) 
   {
   print $arr1[$i]."\r\n\r\n";
  sleep(5);

  $in = $arr1[$i];
  $in = str_replace(' ','+',$in); // space is a +
 //google site search start here

$result = httpGet("https://www.google.com/cse?cx=003255331468891731323:xyxyxyxyxyyx&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&q='$in'");

echo $result;
}
```

Here we have a long string of few pages which we have broken it into small arrays of say 30 words each. These array we have passed in a FOR loop, to get the result (various links) , we have printed the result with echo. We have also applied Sleep of 5 sec so that server gets time to get the result and print it , wait for 5 seconds before searching another query.

But when we are running this for loop, we are not getting result , rather our application hangs, and gives us the result as below:

**Internal Server Error**

**The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.**

**Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@checkforplag.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.**

**More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YVkG.png)

Kindly suggest what all do we need to do to apply GSS completely in our application.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for that by sending my php script in background process, and for that i used shell_exec.

This is the code i used:

```
$status = shell_exec("nohup /usr/bin/php test.php > /dev/null 2>&1 &");
```

And now i am not getting this kind of error even i am running a large file.